# Does the curve $c(t)=\langle \sqrt{1-t^2}\cos t,\sqrt{1-t^2}\sin t,t\rangle$ lie on unit sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

> Given curve $c(t)=\langle \sqrt{1-t^2}\cos t,\sqrt{1-t^2}\sin t,t\rangle$ and $|t|\le 1$ does the curve lie on a sphere which has radius of $1$ and is centered at $(0,0,0)$?

I thought that:
$$
x=\sqrt{1-t^2}\cos t\implies\cos t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\\
y=\sqrt{1-t^2}\sin t\implies\sin t=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
but I have no idea what to do with $z$ coordinate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
The equation for a unit sphere of radius $1$ centered at the origin has the Cartesian equation:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

Can you show that your parameterization satisfies this equation?

Comment: Yes I the equality holds with the parametric curve. What does that prove?

Comment: @Yos If your parametric curve satisfies this equation it means that it lies on the sphere of radius 1. Any triple $(x,y,z)$ given by your curve will satisfy this equation and thus lie on the sphere. It is the analogue to showing the parameterization $(\cos t, \sin t)$ lies on the unit circle of radius 1.

Comment: Intuitively I understand that but I wonder if there can be other surface such that the equality holds but it's not a sphere

Comment: @Yos If any other surface defined by a parameterization satisfies the equation above, it will also lie on the unit sphere. The equality holds if and only if the parameterization lies on the unit sphere. This is how I understand it as an undergraduate, so I can not really give a deep insight to it.

Comment: @Yos: The definition of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R} ^{3}$ is "the set of all points $(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R} ^{3}$ which satisfy the equation $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1,$" so no. Any surface for which all the points satisfy this equation must, by definition, be a subset of the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

$$|c(t)|=\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-t^2})^2+t^2}=1$$ using  that 
 $\cos^2{t}+\sin^2{t}=1$.

So $c(t)$ lies on the unit sphere.